# show posts filtered by language rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I have in my project rails 3.2 two languages.

```
I18n.default_locale = :en
LANGUAGES = [
['English',
'en'],
["Espa&ntilde;ol".html_safe, 'es']
]
```

The registered users can create new posts in these languages.

**My question is:**

In my post action index, if user in these moment the language is for example `:en`. How can I filter and show only posts that are in the English language or if user in these moment the language is for example `:es`. How can I filter and show only posts that are in the Spanish language?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve that is to add a "language" column in your Posts table and to set this attribute when the post is created by testing i18n.locale. Then you filter posts with a simple query like:

```
 Post.where("language = ?", "spanish").
```

The best thing to do would be to let the user choose the language when creating a new post with a select field for instance, and setting the default according to the current locale.

Because, an English user should be able to write Spanish posts if he wants to, shouldn't he?

Comment: Thank you @Kulgar, I have a switch select field in app for language. I had also thought about doing it this way, but not if it was the most correct way. a english user must write a post or article in english language, and spanish user must write in spanish language. Thank you!